# Change MySQL Timezone on shared server

Tags: mysql, timezone, php

I'm on a shared server and want to change the MySQL time zone.
I added  `SetEnv TZ Asia/Calcutta` in `.htaccess` and it just changed PHP's time settings.
Is there any way to change the MySQL timezone setting from htaccess or PHP.INI ?

Answer (score 2):

No. MySQL settings cannot be controlled from Apache. You must edit the my.cnf file.

Perhaps it is possible to alter the session timezone from your scripts, by executing 
    SET SESSION time_zone = YOURTZ;

Take a look at the documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html